# phantom parameter in function

Tags: javascript

Going through some examples on building a video control panel for an HTML5  element and a a pattern I don't understand popped up here?

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-html5-video/#scripting

in particular:

```
var v = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
v.addEventListener('timeupdate',updateTimeDisplay,true);

function updateTimeDisplay(e) {
  document.getElementById('timeDisplay').innerHTML = e.target.currentTime;
}
```

Where did that 'e' come from in the function? What does it reference? Where can I learn more about what it is doing?

Answer (score 0):

That e is the parameter sent into the callback function updateTimeDisplay, by the videoplayer element.  The callback is called when the event 'timeupdate' is triggered in the element referenced by the id videoPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

the e is the event that is always passed to functions triggered by events. In it you can find all information according to the event such as the X and Y mouse position, the element that triggered it and more.

In your exemple, e.target referes to the element that triggered the event.